# Finding documents with a time-range which intersect a given time-range

Tags: couchdb

There is a list of documents `P` having two timestamps representing the time range `[ P    ]` in which the document is valid. An index over these intervals was created:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([doc.start, doc.end], someStuff(doc));
}
```

We want to receive documents `P` which start before some **end timestamp `E`** and stop after some **start timestamp `S`**:

```
P(S, E) = { P | P_s <= E && P_e >= S }
```

For instance, in a picture like this

```
<-- TIME -->
..------------------S-------------------------------------E----------------------..
.. P0 ][ P1          ][ P2          ][ P3  ][ P4              ][ P5      ][ P6   ..
```

we expected the subset `{P1, P2, P3, P4}` as the result. We try to get the desired result using the following key-range

```
_view/range?descending=false&startkey=[0,S]&endkey=[E,{}]
```

The result `P(A, E) = {P0, P1, P2, P3, P4}` is wrong which makes sense when checking the following example for `S=17` and `E=30`:

```
key       startkey             endkey      accept
_________________________________________________________________________
[10,15]   [0,17] <= [10,15] <= [30, {}] -> True  <- This is wrong
[15,25]   [0,17] <= [15,25] <= [30, {}] -> True    OK
[25,30]   [0,17] <= [25,30] <= [30, {}] -> True    OK
[25,50]   [0,17] <= [25,50] <= [30, {}] -> True    OK
[35,50]   [0,17] <= [35,50] <= [30, {}] -> False   OK
```

Is it possible to define a range such that we get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to achieve using the [POST /db/_find](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html?highlight=_find) endpoint. You can express your query as a `selector`:

```
{ 
  "selector": {
     "start": { "$lt": 100 },
     "end": { "$gt": 300 }
   }
   "sort": ["start"]
}
```

This is the equivalent to the SQL `SELECT * FROM db WHERE start<100 AND end > 300 SORY BY start`.

You will almost certainly need an [index](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/find.html?highlight=_find#db-index) on "start" too to speed things up.

Comment: i got some trouble with the index creation, but in principle it works, thanks!